# React Native: set TextInput value to 00:00

Tags: javascript, react-native

I guess its a simple problem. I have a RN App and in a TextInput I want to display some value.

The TextInput value should be shown as 00:00 and a user can modify this value to for ex. be 06:00. How can I render the TextInput to show a value of 00:00?

```
<Text style={styles.timeText} >Time:</Text>
                    <TextInput style={styles.timeInp} keyboardType={"numeric"} 
                    value={this.state.time} onChange={(time) => this.setState({time})} />
```

It kinda looks like this but I cant get the value to be shown like 00:00.

Ty in advance.

Comment: You can do it set the initial state with hours: 00, minutes:00,, And after interaction you can update the state value of hours and minutes. 
But recommended is - you should use third-party package like moment for handling times or dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mark the time or the date,

```
import moment from "moment";
...
let date = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-D-ss");
```

If you're just trying to get the data in there,

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
         time: "06:00"
        };
      }
...
<TextInput style={styles.timeInp} 
keyboardType={"numeric"} 
value={this.state.time} 
onChangeText={(time) => this.setState({time})} />
```

As mentioned in the example, you can set "06:00" to the default setting.

and Clear the `06:00` entered in `TextInput` and enter a new `00:00`.

Comment: When I put the state to : "00:00" it shows in the input but when I click into it and only want to change the second 0 for ex a 8 (08:00) then the whole input gets cleared. Do you know how to make it stay and how to only edit 1 number? and i also get a warning saying that : an invalid prop is passed to value - Object but expected String.


EDIT -- Nevermind i put onChange and not onChangeText it works with onChangeText thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it's settled.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, could you choose an my answer?

Comment: what do you mean sorry I dont get it ?

Comment: If my answer was helpful, there is a 'V' sign on the right under the < 0>' mark, and I would appreciate it if you could check it.

Comment: aight gotcha bro

Answer (score 0):

You have two options,

Add a picker to select time

OR

Add two `TextInput` for select hours and minutes, 
eg:

Add two state values for Hour and Minute

```
this.state = {
 ...
 hour: "00",
 min: "00"
};
```

And add two text input for both Hour and Minute

```
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <Text style={{}}>{"Time :    "}</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={{}}
            keyboardType={"numeric"}
            value={this.state.hour}
            onChange={hour => {
              this.setState({ hour: hour });
            }}
          />
          <Text style={{}}>{":"}</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={{}}
            keyboardType={"numeric"}
            value={this.state.min}
            onChange={min => {
              this.setState({ min: min });
            }}
          />
     </View>
```